# Hide/Show div based on checkbox selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm building a form that's supposed to hide and show content according to checkbox selections made by the user. No luck so far in identifying where the error in my code is. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

```js
function documentFilter(trigger, target) {

$(trigger).change(function () {
    if ($(trigger).checked)
        $(target).show();
    else
        $(target).hide();
    });
}

documentFilter("triggerDiv", "hideableDiv");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="checkbox" id="triggerDiv" > Some caption   </label>

<div id="hideableDiv" class="well">
    Some hidable content </div>
```

Comment: You need to pass in '#...' to get the jQuery object you want.'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were not sending the correct jQuery string to your function.

Change:

```
documentFilter("triggerDiv", "hideableDiv");
```

to:

```
documentFilter("#triggerDiv", "#hideableDiv"); // notice the '#'s to grab ids
```

It would be more concise to just toggle the hideableDiv whenever the checkbox state changes.

If the checkbox state is always unchecked on load, just hide the div on page load.

If the checkbox state is determined dynamically, then you'd need to check the prop checked state on page load to hide or show the div initially.

```js
function documentFilter(trigger, target) {
    $(trigger).on('change', function () {
        $(target).toggle();
    });
}
documentFilter("#triggerDiv", "#hideableDiv");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="checkbox" id="triggerDiv" > Some caption   </label>

<div id="hideableDiv" class="well" style="display:none">
    Some hidable content </div>
```

Comment: This will not work because you need to use .prop to access checked property

Comment: @EugeneTsakh did you try the snippet? It works fine. The error was with the jQuery string. Any other changes are not fixing the error.

Comment: You can't just use toggle without passing current checkbox state. What if when page loaded the checkbox is checked but target hidden?

Comment: You set the initial state and it simple toggles on changes.

Comment: It is bad bractice and can produce bugs.

Comment: It depends on the requirements how to handle each situation. If the checkbox is always unchecked on page load, there is no reason to check the state. Simpler/more readable code leads to less bugs and easier maintenance.

Answer (score 0):

1. Your selectors are bad. If you want to find by id you shoud use # before id
2. To get checked state use .prop
3. You can use .toggle(state) to show/hide element according to passed state

Try this:

```
function documentFilter(trigger, target) {
    var $target = $(target);

    $(trigger).change(function() {
        $target.toggle(this.checked);
    });
}

documentFilter("#triggerDiv", "#hideableDiv");
```

Answer (score 0):

Your selectors aren't the best. I'd do the following:

1. Hide the `div` when the page loads using jQuery's `.hide()`
2. Listen for the checkbox to be clicked
3. When the checkbox is clicked, check to see if the current state of the checkbox is checked using `this.checked`
4. Based on the current state, either `hide()` or `show()`

***DEMO: http://jsbin.com/zukobufefe/edit?html,js,output***

```
$("#hideableDiv").hide();

$("input[type=checkbox]").click(function() {

     if (this.checked) 
     {
         $("#hideableDiv").show();
     } 
     else 
     {
         $("#hideableDiv").hide();
     }

});
```